# Access specific row from spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am a newbie to azure spark/ databricks and trying to access specific row e.g. 10th row in the dataframe.

This is what I did in notebook so far

**1. Read a CSV file in a table**

```
spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("/mnt/training/enb/commonfiles/ramp.csv")
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .saveAsTable("ramp_csv")
```

**2. Create a DataFrame for the "table" ramp_csv**

```
val rampDF = spark.read.table("ramp_csv")
```

**3. Read specific row**

I am using the following logic in Scala

```
val myRow1st = rampDF.rdd.take(10).last

display(myRow1st)
```

and it should display 10th row but I am getting the following error

```
command-2264596624884586:9: error: overloaded method value display with alternatives:
  [A](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Unit <and>
  (dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],streamName: String,trigger: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger,checkpointLocation: String)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel)Unit <and>
  (documentable: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.WithHelpMethods)Unit
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Row)
display(myRow1st)
^
Command took 0.12 seconds --
```

Could you please share what I am missing here? I tried few other things but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the breakdown of what is happening in your code:

`rampDF.rdd.take(10)` returns `Array[Row]`

`.last` returns `Row`

`display()` takes a `Dataset` and you are passing it a `Row`. You can use `.show(10)` to display the first 10 rows in tabular form.

Another option is to do `display(rampDF.limit(10))`

Comment: Thanks for sharing detailed answer. ```display(rampDF.limit(10))``` worked but it'll give me first 10 rows. Could you please share what will be the approach to access just row#10.

Comment: The way you did it works just for getting row 10 but it means collecting the data to the driver. If all you want is to print the data you can get the string representation of the row with `myRow1st.mkString(",")`. Here I used , as a col separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with João's answer as well. But if you insist on getting the Nth row as a `DataFrame` and avoid collecting to the driver node (say when N is very big) you can do:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = 1 to 100 toDF //sample data
val cols = df.columns

df
.limit(10)
.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
.agg(max(struct(("id" +: cols).map(col(_)):_*)).alias("tenth"))
.select(cols.map(c => col("tenth."+c).alias(c)):_*)
```

This will return:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   10|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I also go with João Guitana's answer. An alternative to get specifically the 10'th record:

```
val df = 1 to 1000 toDF
val tenth = df.limit(10).collect.toList.last
tenth: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [10]
```

That will return the 10th `Row` on that `df`